# Stripping suffix from all elements of string cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array containing strings, called `old_array`. Each element ends with the suffix '.dat'. I want to create a new cell array, called `new_array`, that has the same elements, but without this suffix.

I know that the following function exists:

```
[new_array] = arrayfun(func, old_array)
```

But what do I use for `func`? I thought about using `strsplit(str, '.')` and taking the first element of this array, something like:

```
[new_array] = arrayfun(strsplit(*, '.')[0], old_array)
```

But what do I place instead of the `*`? What's the best solution?

Comment: You almost have it.  I made an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **every** element in your array ends with `.dat`, why don't you simply extract all of the characters except the last 4 for each string in your cell array?

```
new_array = cellfun(@(x) x(1:end-4), old_array, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

This should return a new cell array stored in `new_array` where each element loses the last 4 characters of each string from the cell array `old_array`, which is the string `.dat` for each string in `old_array`.

---

However, if you want to make this more robust and if you want to accommodate any file name, you can use `strsplit` like what you have in your post.  You would have to structure it like so:

```
%// Use to split up the strings for each cell and store in individual cells
new_array_temp = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x, '.'), old_array, 'UniformOutput', false);
%// Extract the first cell of each nested cell
new_array = cellfun(@(x) x{1}, new_array_temp, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

We need to do the first step so that we can return a cell array of cells.  Each nested cell within the larger cell array will contain strings that are delimited by `.` within the nested cell element.  You then run the next command so that we extract the **first** string of each nested cell, which is the file name itself before the `.`.

Here's an example that shows you how this is run, as well as the intermediate outputs:

```
old_array = {'Hi.dat', 'how.dat', 'are.dat', 'you.dat'};

new_array_temp = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x, '.'), old_array, 'UniformOutput', false);
celldisp(new_array_temp);

new_array_temp{1}{1} =

Hi


new_array_temp{1}{2} =

dat


new_array_temp{2}{1} =

how


new_array_temp{2}{2} =

dat


new_array_temp{3}{1} =

are


new_array_temp{3}{2} =

dat


new_array_temp{4}{1} =

you


new_array_temp{4}{2} =

dat
```

---

```
new_array = cellfun(@(x) x{1}, new_array_temp, 'UniformOutput', false);
disp(new_array);

 'Hi'    'how'    'are'    'you'
```

---

## Minor note

Note: `strsplit` only works for MATLAB R2013a and up.  If you want this to work with previous versions of MATLAB, use `regexp`.  Replace the `strsplit` call within `cellfun` with this:

```
new_array_temp = cellfun(@(x) regexp(x, '\.', 'split'), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

This should basically achieve the same thing as `strsplit`.  However, if you **really, really, really, really** want to use `strsplit`, there is an implementation on the MathWorks File Exchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21710-string-toolkits/content/strings/strsplit.m